# Azure Service Bus in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to subscribe to Azure Service Bus Queue using Xamarin forms. (To be honest, I am not sure if it is possible to do it at all.)

I can receive a message from the queue using a simple Console app without any issues. However, when I move the same code to Xamarin, It fails in two different scenarios.

Rarely, it works fine  and I receive message (after a 1-2 minutes though) but it gives `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTimeoutException: 'The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:59.9923240 for object dispose.'`
 error when it tries to complete the message at this line `await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);`

Other times, it fails without even receiving any message and gives this error `The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:56.2875140 for object session5.`.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static IQueueClient queueClient;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            var serviceBusConnectionString = "myConnectionString";
            var queueName = "myqueueName";

            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler);
            messageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
            messageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;

            queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }

        private static async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to subscribe properly for the Azure Service Bus queue
   at all using Xamarin?
2. Am I missing something here?
3. Do I have any other alternative to send a JSON object from the service bus to the phone?

Comment: Interestingly I am having the same problem, but in sending to a queue rather than receiving. I say interesting because it has been working for around 2 years and suddenly as of around May it stopped working and I am now getting the same timeout exception as you. I wonder whether anything has changed

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, I did find when implementing a similar subscribe pattern in a Xamarin app that Signal R worked better and is very easy and lightweight to implement. It's subjective but I did find the negotiation method of connecting neater than having to connect directly to an Azure Service bus endpoint